# Problem with distance between figure and text, when referring the figure as table

Tags: spacing, floats

I made extensive data analysis using Excel, included tables from there in my LaTeX document as figures and referred them as tables:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\captionof{table}{Data...}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio] 
{pics/my_nice_table}
\label{tab:DAGesamtStreu2GKanzahl}
\end{figure}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

Problem is that I don't know how to adjust the spaces between caption and table as well as  table and the text that follows, without changing my global settings. Because I also have other pictures and tables in this doc for which everything is like I want it.

Comment: There’s no reason to use a figure and \captionof{table}. Just use table. LaTeX doesn’t care what’s inside a float.

Comment: Also, there are in fact tools that will help you convert an MS Excel table to LaTeX code. On sidenote: I saw in your image that you use different numbers of decimals that makes the table a bit hard to read.

Comment: The lengths you are looking for are `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.  With the caption package , use `\captionsetup[position=above]`.  OTOH, some of that white space seems to come from the image.  Try putting an `\fbox` around it.